# Admob account setup - what does "How you pay" and "What you pay with" means?

Tags: google-play, admob

I have developed an android app and included admob banner ads (test ad) in it. Now I want to create a admob account and get a ad unit ID.

While setting up my account, I want to provide the payment details and methods by which the money from ad revenue will be sent to me.

When filling up the form, the payments screen says None selected. So I went to the "Billing" screen. [image: screenshot 1]

[image]

The billing screen has option to add bank details, but why it says "How you pay" and "What you pay with". Why do I have anything to pay at all? I am obviously doing something wrong.

Can anyone please let me know where can I provide the payment methods where I will receive the ad revenue?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong. After you earn minimum 10$ in your admob account. Then None Selected option will be available to you. In that option their will be choices available for you to attach bank or western union etc depending on your country.

I got 4$ in my admob account and i also have no option for setting bank for getting money. But in this month i got more then 100$ but still their is no option.. Admob still saying non selected. I am waiting for next month. then it will b available because after each month your earning is transfer to admob account.. other wise it is on hold the whole month..