# Does the play store payment setting override the AdMob payment method?

Tags: admob, google-play-services

At play.google.com/console, under "how you get paid", my account is set up correctly.

But on apps.admob.com, under payments and "how you get paid", I am told: "no primary payment method selected". No surprise here: after setting up the AdMob account payment method, I removed it.

I waited for two weeks after initially setting up the payment method, and receiving (and confirming) a small deposit. But no ads were appearing.

Now ads have just started appearing on my app, despite that I removed the payment method from apps.admob.com, in anticipation of experimenting with a different account (such as a new bank account that the bank identifies as a corporate one, to match the setting on AdMob—a business, not personal, AdMob account).

Does the play store payment setting override (and make redundant) the AdMob payment method?

Does the mere appearance of ads on my app (downloaded from the play store) indicate that the payment method is set up correctly, and I need not worry that AdMob says "no primary payment method selected"?

Is it accurate that "choose payment method" [will become an option after I reach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972586/704972) the "payout threshold"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the play store payment setting override (and make redundant) the AdMob payment method?

```
-> No they are different
```

Does the mere appearance of ads on my app (downloaded from the play store) indicate that the payment method is set up correctly, and I need not worry that AdMob says "no primary payment method selected"?

```
-> Only need to worry when you cross your threshold value
```

To display advertisements, payment method need not be setup. Please see below checklist for receiving the payment.

https://support.google.com/admob/checklist/2998383

```
The first time you reach the payment threshold, you'll need to select your form of payment.
```

Link to help to Policy center that might affect your advertisement servicing
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9192065

Admob Help center link - https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=2745287

Comment: Re: "_To display advertisements, payment method need not be setup._" I recall reading exactly the opposite. Google will not display even one ad unless the developer already has a method of payment set up, _and_ has confirmed that method of payment by reporting back the amount of a small deposit. Has this policy just changed?

Comment: @Calaf - i'm not aware of that policy. As per my knowledge, showing advertisements and payment method are not linked. From May 2021 - App advertisements will be limited if you don't link your app to play store ( but that shoudn't affect your case .. i think ) . Here is link to all admob policies https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=2745287